# Зачем запятая в названии фильма?

Tags: пунктуация

Фильм:
«История Аси Клячиной, которая любила, да не вышла замуж (1967)». Почему здесь запятая перед «да»? В значении «но»?

Comment: да. *(нужно ещё 12 символов...)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.........................................................................................................................................................................................................
[image]